# how to filter an array when I use an array like geojson format

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array , and I want to filter the Array with BHID.

```
let array = [
{ 
 "type": "Feature",   
 "properties": 
        {
        "PID": 0, "SID": 2, "BHID": 1,
        }
},
{ 
 "type": "Feature",   
 "properties": 
        {
        "PID": 0, "SID": 8, "BHID": 2,
        },
},
{ 
 "type": "Feature",   
 "properties": 
        {
        "PID": 0, "SID": 5, "BHID": 1,
        },
}

]
```

and then I try to filter the array by BHID:

```
    for (let id = 0; id < maxId + 1; id++) {
      let entriesWithID = array.filter((entry) => {
        entry.properties.BHID === id;
      for (let i = 0; i < entriesWithID.length; i++) {
        console.log(entriesWithID[i]);
         }
      });
```

But I cannot get the correct result,  what should I do to get the correct result.

Comment: The `for (let i = 0; i < entriesWithID.length` should be outside of your `.filter()` callback function, and you should be returning using `return entry.properties.BHID === id;`

Comment: If I understood correctly what you want to do, you could simply have: `const filteredArray = array.filter(item => item.properties.BHID <= maxId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the resulting `entriesWithID` at each iteration in an object as follows:

```js
const array = [
  { 
    "type": "Feature",   
    "properties": { "PID": 0, "SID": 2, "BHID": 1 }
  },
  { 
    "type": "Feature",   
    "properties": { "PID": 0, "SID": 8, "BHID": 2 }
  },
  { 
    "type": "Feature",   
    "properties":  { "PID": 0, "SID": 5, "BHID": 1 }
  }
];
const maxId = 2;
const res = {};

for (let id = 0; id < maxId + 1; id++) {
  const entriesWithID = array.filter(entry => entry.properties.BHID === id);
  res[id] = entriesWithID;
}

console.log(res);
```

**Another Approach:**

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can iterate over the `array` and group the items in an object by the `BHID` in the range you want. This will only store the categories found in the array with no empty ones:

```js
const array = [
  { 
    "type": "Feature",   
    "properties": { "PID": 0, "SID": 2, "BHID": 1 }
  },
  { 
    "type": "Feature",   
    "properties": { "PID": 0, "SID": 8, "BHID": 2 }
  },
  { 
    "type": "Feature",   
    "properties":  { "PID": 0, "SID": 5, "BHID": 1 }
  }
];
const maxId = 2;

const res = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const bhId = item.properties.BHID;
  if(bhId >= 0 && bhId <= maxId) {
    acc[bhId] = [ ...(acc[bhId] || []), item ];
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the boolean condition check in the `filter` method.

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this.

Change your code like this.

```
for (let id = 0; id < maxId + 1; id++) {
  let entriesWithID = array.filter((entry) => {
    return entry.properties.BHID === id;
  });
```